# Backward compatibility of Springboot 2.3.4

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mongo-java-driver

I am using spring boot 2.0.4 for a project, and need to upgrade the mongo driver to version 4.1.

I understand that springboot 2.3.4 upgrades ([here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/releases)) MongoDB to version 4.1, but it doesn't clearly says if it is MongoDB version or MongoDriver.

Seems like springboot v2.3.4 is not backward compatible and my project starts failing build for missing class `ChannelAwareMessageListener`.
Trying to find the class path for this class, and how can I make it backward compatible with minimum changes. Otherwise, I would have to exclude the Mongo driver from Springboot mongo starter and add it as a separate dependency, which defeats the spring boot dependency version management goal.